# Why Intro js disableInteraction doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript, intro.js

I have created a tour and I want the items highlighted to be clickable so I added attribute disable interaction to the tour but the items are still not clickable.

```
this.introJS.setOptions({
      tooltipClass: 'customTooltip',
      highlightClass: 'customHighlight',
      exitOnOverlayClick: false,
      disableInteraction: false,
      steps: [
        {
          intro: 'Welcome to the web let me show you around!',
        },
        {
          element: document.getElementById('step3'),
          intro: 'Fill out the form',
          position: 'right'
        },
        {
          element: document.querySelector('#step4'),
          intro: 'Click Create an account',
          position: 'right'
        }
      ]
    }).start();
```

I'm using angular so the elements are in app root that is a sibling to all the Intro js elements.